# Storing some class fields in more than one table simultaneously using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

How I should design my classes so as to store some fields of class in more than one table.

```
class Child
{
private int id;
private String name;
private int age;
private String favGame;
}
```

I want to create two tables-

Table 1 :
containing id, name, age and favGame

Table 2 :
name and age

Also I want a referential integrity between these two tables, so that whenever a record is created/updated/deleted in table1, table2 should also get updated.

I have seen @secondaryTable concept in the following link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3Bct8tkfcs

but It does not provide option to store a field in two tables simultaneously.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? If at times you need only a projection of your data in your app, write an appropriate query. If you want only a subset of your data to be accessible to another app, use database views

Comment: Agree with you crizzis.. but in my case it is needed as per third party database design.

Comment: I don't think I follow... you said you needed to *create* a database table. If I understand correctly, ' third party database design' implies something other than your app will consume your data and that something expects a certain logical schema to exist. A database view seems a perfect fit here. If I'm wrong then please describe the issue in more detail

Comment: Yes crizzis,  ' third party database design' implies something other than your app will consume your data and that something expects a certain logical schema to exist. Hence I can't change this schema.

Comment: You don't need to change the schema, just create a view instead of a table. Whatever is querying your database will not tell the difference. From what you described, `Table2` is effectively read-only anyway